# Wird der Kasuswirkungsbereich einer Präposition in einer Apposition der Form „..., also [Objekt] , ...“ ausgelöscht?

Tags: grammar, inflection, apposition

Im Satz(versuch)

> …er hat den Bericht zum Zeitraum Juni 2012 bis Mai 2013, also ein**em** Jahr, geschrieben…

weiß ich nicht, ob „also einem Jahr“ als Apposition fungiert und ob es in dem Fall auch die Endung *em* braucht, oder ob man schon die Präposition *zu* vergessen kann.

Hilft einem *also* zu vergessen, dass *zu* da ist? Das ist vielleicht kein gehobener Schreibstil, aber den Satz könnte es wenigstens mündlich geben (hoffe ich).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich habe jetzt viel hin- und herüberlegt und bin zu folgendem Schluss gekommen:

**Die Apposition sollte** (zumindest in der Schriftsprache) **weiterhin den Kasus des näher beschriebenen Satzgliedes tragen.**

Beim Herumprobieren mit und ohne *-em* ist mir eine potenzielle Bedeutungsverschiebung aufgefallen:

> […] den Bericht zum Zeitraum Juni bis Mai, also **dem Jahr** nach Markteintritt des Konkurrenzprodukts, […]
>
> […] den Bericht zum Zeitraum Juni bis Mai, also **ein Jahr** nach Markteintritt des Konkurrenzprodukts, […]

Im ersten Fall ist das Konkurrenzprodukt im Mai oder Juni 2012 auf den Markt gekommen, und der Bericht beschreibt, wie sich das eigene Produkt in der Zeit entwickelt hat. Im zweiten Fall ist das Konkurrenzprodukt im Mai oder Juni **2011** auf den Markt gekommen, und der Bericht beschreibt, welche Auswirkungen es ein Jahr später gegeben hat.

Letzteres braucht auf jeden Fall einen Bezugspunkt, Ersteres kann auch nur eine Verdeutlichung des Zeitraums für Rechenunwillige sein. Deswegen erschien mir wahrscheinlich *ein* ohne Endung falsch, ohne dass ich festnageln konnte, woran das lag.

Umschiffen kannst du das Problem manchmal, indem du, wie vorgeschlagen, *über* statt *zu* schreibst:

> […] er hat den Bericht über den Zeitraum Juni 2012 bis Mai 2013, also ein Jahr, geschrieben, […]

Jetzt hast du den Akkusativ, und der ist im Neutrum gleich dem Nominativ. Aber Achtung:

> […] er hat den Bericht über den Zeitraum 15. Juni bis 14. Juli, also ein**en** Monat, geschrieben, […]

**Mündlich** sieht das nochmal ganz anders aus:

Es gibt in vielen Dialekten und Umgangssprachen die Tendenz, Endungen des Wortes *ein* zu verschlucken und zu vergessen. Demnach wäre es in weiten Teilen Deutschlands, vielleicht auch der Schweiz durchaus möglich, immer von *ein Jahr* zu sprechen. Teilweise haben diese Dialekte und Umgangssprachen auch die Tendenz, statt *ein* *nen* zu sagen (was für meine Ohren grausam klingt). Allerdings ist es auch möglich, dass die Sprecher unbewusst ein *nem* stattdessen erwarten, wo der Dativ stehen muss.

Aber Vorsicht: Andere Dialekte, zum Beispiel Bairisch, unterscheiden *ein, einem, einen* (im Beispiel: *oa, oam, oan*). Da muss auf jeden Fall der richtige Fall auftauchen. (Deswegen vermute ich auch, dass das Zusammenfallen von *einen* und *ein* in Österreich eher ungewöhnlich sein müsste.)

Comment: Danke. Was du über die Apposition behauptest, glaube ich, ist eine Regel. Die Frage war eher ob die Struktur " `Komma`+ `also`+ `Beschreibung`+`Komma`" als Apposition fungieren kann oder muss, und konsequent für die die von dir erwähnten Regel gilt. Aber das hast du auch hier beantwortet.